# Downloading and installing an application in the system/app on a un-rooted device

Tags: android

Is it possible to install an application in the system/app directory on a un-rooted device? Right now I can do it on a rooted device, so I was wondering what I have to do to if the device is not rooted, its a custom rom so I can get hold of the certificates that signed the rom. Currently if I try on a un-rooted device I get the permission denied (read_only file system). If anybody has an idea of how I can do this please help me, the reason why I need this done is so I can do app updates on the system applications that will be shipped with the rom and they wont be on the app store.

Comment: You can't. You would have to build a custom unrooted rom that includes your APK.

Comment: Can I then update that APK using a service included on the unrooted rom?

Comment: If you have it installed as a system app on your custom rom you can install updates (unrooted) as you would a normal app. The user will be able to uninstall the updates, which would roll it back to the bundled version.

Comment: Thanks. So what this means is that the applications will have to be signed together with the rom, if they aren't it wont work, even if I use the same certificate that originally signed the rom, unroot the phone, move the applications to system/app then unroot the phone?

Comment: I think that for some permissions (you can lookup which on Google's Android doc pages) you need just platform SIGNATURE. In that case you can even install those apps after-market on your device and get permissions that no normal app could normally get, provided you sign the app with your platform key. For SYSTEM level permission, your app will need to be in the /system/app folder, which you can basically only do if you provide it with your platform. I have to admit that I have never tried your rooting, copying, unrooting solution. For updating a system app, Leonard is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks, technically it makes sense but I will try it out and see whats happens.

Comment: What was the result of your experiments? I'm also interested in this.

Comment: I'm also interested in this , what happen ?

Comment: You can check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039718/how-to-convert-an-app-to-be-a-system-app-in-android-5-0-without-rooting-the-dev/56041185#56041185. The detail demonstration is given there.