# How to convert an app to be a system app in android +5.0 without rooting the device?

Tags: android, mobile-development

One of the biggest school has its own Android tablets which distributed among several branches and it's already with the students a long time ago.

We need to develop an app and put it in the play store normally and all the students have to download the app but this time we need the app to run as a system app and take the full control of the devices ( without rooting the device )
we need to prevent some malware apps from installing, access the wifi, mic, and camera, etc 
so we make sure the students use the tablets in studying and exams only.

We search a lot and found that most of the answers are for android 5 and earlier. but there are many apps in the play store doing so.

So how to develop the app to run as a system app without rooting the device and without installing a custom ROM?

Comment: "So how to develop the app to run as a system app without rooting the device or installing a custom ROM?" -- you don't. "but there are many apps in the play store doing so" -- such as? My guess is that you are confusing "device admin" or "device owner" apps with system apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your replying I may be confused between these terms so I explain what we intended to do,
the apps like Citrix as I remember now.
we don't want to use any other apps we want to develop our own solution so what is your recommendation?

Comment: "the apps like Citrix as I remember now" -- based on the Play Store description, the Citrix app does not do anything of what you describe. "so what is your recommendation?" -- work with a device manufacturer to build a custom device with a custom ROM that meets your needs. Along the way, I recommend that you work with qualified legal counsel, as some of what you describe may be against the law in your jurisdiction.

Comment: @CommonsWare the problem is that the devices are already with the students now, we cannot take the devices from thousands of students now so we need to develop a solution for that.
and do not be worry we do not break any law at all.

Comment: you likely want a device admin app, you can use search to find how they work. It will still be probably cheaper to use existing solution instead of developing your own

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can the user delete the device admin app?

Comment: yes, he can. If you want the non-removable app, then you will either have to root the device, or to build your custom ROM. Just think if it would be possible to build such app, and make it unremovable? How many malware would this possibility produce? Citrix can be easily removed as an app just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install an app to any mobile as System app because system app should be signed with the same key as of the firmware apps. If not then it will be treated as non system app and it should maintain the permission restrictions. You can see some basic difference between System App and User App at [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17871/what-are-the-differences-between-a-system-app-and-user-app).

Regarding Citrix, as per my knowledge this is not a fully native app rather it manages a secure virtual container as app's own environment where it performs all the resource related activities. It does not do anything locally in the physical location such as mobile device. You can get a basic idea about Citrix at [link](https://www.citrix.com/digital-workspace/mam.html).

As a conclusion, it is not feasible to make your app as System app. But it is possible if you can have legal agreement with the mobile vendor(s) so that the app can be signed with their firmware apps signature.

Comment: thanks a lot, 
what about making the app as device admin app?
using such a thing, can we fully control the student device? and adding restrictions to prevent using any apps rather than exam app while the exam for example?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I don't think you can control to access the other app by making your Admin App. Infact a user can enable or disable this administrator permission from phone setting. There is a possibility to make your app as single app. You can get a basic concept from the link https://www.42gears.com/blog/single-application-mode/. But I don't think it would be auto configured after installation as you are looking for because there might have some configuration to be done when installing it.